# I can not access my wordpress admin after editing in wp-config

Tags: wordpress

I am migrating a Local WordPress Site I made to a server using Cyberduck. I was installing a plugin called wordpress importer when it gave me an error message. I tried to google the problem online and found: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/can-t-install-wordpress-themes-ftp-error, where they said that I could place this line of code in my wp-config.php define('FS_METHOD', 'direct'); This crashed my site :( And I am no longer allowed to access my wp-admin panel and it gives me a HTTP ERROR 500...

I would very much appreciate the help - this is for an exam that has to be uploaded very soon, and I've worked so hard on it and then this happened :(

Comment: Have you any backup of the wp-config.php?

Comment: No but I changed it back to the original one (deleted the code I inserted right away)

Comment: Try reinstalling wp.

Comment: I got it up and running again now :) Thanks for the quick reply though!

Comment: @Maria share the solution, if someone have the same problem.

Comment: I had made a stupid mistake and forgotten to put the wp-config.php (the one without the snippet of code that broke it all) back in my themes folder.